# wordpress uploaded images give broken link image

Tags: wordpress

When I look in my media library all my new uploaded images get a broken link image. I already changed my upload folder permissions to 755 but that didn't work. What's going wrong.

Comment: Can you think of any changes that you have made in wordpress before this problem is surfaced?

Comment: Try if this plugin can fix the problem. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wow-media-library-fix/

Comment: if you sort your media from grid to list do they show up?

Comment: @zipkundan not any changes that I can think of. Just making/editing some posts and pages

Comment: @OrlandoP. It was already in a list but that didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALREADY FIXED! My auto increment in the database was gone, thats why he wasn't connecting my images. Thanks for the help.